# How to pass an array of struct as an argument of a function block in codesys

Tags: plc, codesys

How can you pass an array of structure as an argument to a function block?

Initializing the array dirrectly as an argument didn't work:

```pascal
    myFunctionBlock(inArrayOfStruct := [(Param1 := TRUE), (Param1 := FALSE)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message if you try this:

```pascal
fb: FB(inArrayOfStruct := [(Param1 := TRUE), (Param1 := FALSE)]);
```

says it all:

```
[ERROR]  C0304:  An array initialisation is not possible as parameter of an initial function call. Use a variable instead
```

Just use a variable:

```pascal
arr: ARRAY [0..1] OF DUT := [(Param1 := TRUE), (Param1 := FALSE)];
fb: FB(inArrayOfStruct := arr);
```

or

```pascal
arr[0].Param1 := TRUE;
arr[1].Param1 := FALSE;
fb(inArrayOfStruct := arr);
```